# Cassandra upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, updates

Trying to update cassandra from 1.0.11-1 to 1.1.12-1 on Centos 5.5.  Read the docs on http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/upgrading and tried the advised method: yum install apache-cassandra11 to get the package installed; however, am getting depsolving problems.

Is the correct way to update Cassandra is to yum remove and then yum install?

```
[root@cass01 ~]# yum install apache-cassandra11.noarch
Loaded plugins: allowdowngrade, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apache-cassandra11.noarch 0:1.1.12-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: apache-cassandra11 conflicts apache-cassandra1
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apache-cassandra1.noarch 0:1.0.11-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: apache-cassandra11 conflicts apache-cassandra1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
apache-cassandra11-1.1.12-1.noarch from datastax has depsolving problems
  --> apache-cassandra11 conflicts with apache-cassandra1
Error: apache-cassandra11 conflicts with apache-cassandra1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
[root@cass01 ~]#
```